# Is there a way to get a full filepath from an input in Html?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, filepath

I'm developping a web application with ASP Core 3.0 that will be used with Google Chrome.

The user of this app need to be able to specify the location of a file. 
I don't need to upload the file I just need the full path of its location. The file can be in different folders on my company network (this folder is accessible by all future users of the app and by the server hosting it).

Is there a way to get this information ? I know that it's not possible to get it via the html5 input type="file" on chrome.

Since my server has access to this repository, I was thinking of doing ajax call to build the path of this file (basically building a light version of an html5 input file) but I was wondering if there were an easier way...

Any idea ?

Comment: If you don't need to actually upload the file, just get the user to paste in the full path in a textbox. You're right, you can't get it from a "file" input box.

Comment: Either that, or force the user to put the file in a more specific location, and get them just to tell you the filename or something.

Comment: Yeah I aslo thought about that but I was looking for something more user-friendly

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to do it. In a "regular" web app situation, the user would be uploading the file direct, and the source folder would be private, and none of the application's business.

Comment: One approach I've seen used in the past in this scenario is to have a root folder on the network where all files must be placed, and then the user (or the server pre-creates) a folder named with the user's windows username. The user must place the file(s) to be processed in the folder under their username, and when they submit the request in the application the server will collect the files from the folder which matches the username of the person using the application. That removes the need for pasting of folder names. You just need to give the users clear guidance on how to use it.

Comment: Either that or you redevelop this GUI as a desktop app and you use a regular folder-selection dialog to let the user choose a folder. Then the desktop app sends that info (with anything else that's required) in a HTTP request to an API endpoint on the server.